# In a VS extension how to dispaly the some string (which contains the path and line number) in output window

Tags: visual-studio-extensions

I am developing an Extension in VS 2017 using C#.I want to run a Static code analyzer on a button click, whose output will be displayed in the Output window of the Visual Studio with error/warning/info with full path (as that in Building Case) and on double clicking that It should navigate me to the line where error is present.

I am able to add normal string to the output window. But I want in a format so that I can be able to click on it and on click it will navigate me to the line.

```
private void Execute(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Output("Created Pane");
        }
        public static void Output(string msg)
        {
            var pane = GetWindow();
            // Output the message
            pane.OutputString(msg + Environment.NewLine);
        }
        private static IVsOutputWindowPane GetWindow()
        {
            var outputWindow = Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(SVsOutputWindow)) as IVsOutputWindow;

            // Ensure that the desired pane is visible
            var paneGuid = Microsoft.VisualStudio.VSConstants.OutputWindowPaneGuid.GeneralPane_guid;
            IVsOutputWindowPane pane;

            outputWindow.CreatePane(paneGuid, "General", 1, 1);
            outputWindow.GetPane(paneGuid, out pane);
            return pane;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method OutputTaskItemString is what resolved my problem.This will add into error window as well. You can change the VSTASKPRIORITY and VSTASKCATEGORY as per your requirements.

pane.OutputTaskItemString("D:\VSIXDemo\Command1.cs(98): error C2143 : syntax error: missing ';' before '}' \n", Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.VSTASKPRIORITY.TP_HIGH, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.VSTASKCATEGORY.CAT_BUILDCOMPILE, "Error C2143", (int)Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop._vstaskbitmap.BMP_COMPILE, "D:\VSIXDemo\Command1.cs", 98, "Error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'");

//98 is the line number, this will navigate ypou to line no 99 since it is 0 based index

Comment: However "Error C2143" is not displayed in the code of the error list.

Answer (score 1):

You should format the message like this:

```
$"{e.file}({e.line + 1},{e.column}): error {e.code}: {e.message}"
```